# How to prove $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln^2(n)}\cos(\frac{n^2\pi}{n+1})$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

**My Problem:**
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln^2(n)}\cos(\frac{n^2\pi}{n+1})$$
**My progress**

I know this series converges by Dirichlet's test, because $\{\frac{1}{\ln^2(n)}\}$ is decreasing to $0$

and partial sum of $\cos(\frac{n^2\pi}{n+1})$ is bounded. I tried to make it simpler:
$$\cos(\frac{n^2\pi}{n+1}) = \cos(\frac{(n^2-1)\pi+\pi}{n+1}) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{n+1}+(n-1)\pi) = (-1)^n\cos(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$$

But I can't prove the partial sum of $(-1)^n\cos(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$ is bounded. Could anyone give me some tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right).$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=2}^N(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^N(-1)^n-2\sum_{n=2}^N(-1)^n\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}\right).$$
The first partial sum is bounded whereas the second one is convergent by Leibniz.

Comment: Thank a lot! I didn't notice that XD